# Image uploading using codeigniter file uploading class

Tags: image, codeigniter, upload, hmvc

This is not a how to upload image question . I have almost successfully managed to add a image upload function into my add client function . It works well when i try to upload a valid file .. but when i select a invalid file or larger file then it shows undefined variable `upload_data` and codeigniter database error where `img_path` is `NULL` it says `Column 'img_path' cannot be null`. why this function isn't working `$this->upload->display_errors();` . The validation errors are showing nicely but no file validation error showing up.

I am using Codeigniter and hmvc

here is my controller

```
<?php

class Clients extends MX_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mdl_clients');
    }

    function add(){
        $data['success'] = null;
        $data['errors']= null;
        if($_POST){
            $config_arr = array(
                'upload_path'   => './uploads/',
                'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png',
                'max_size'      => '2048',
                'max_width'     => '1024',
                'max_height'    => '768',
                'encrypt_name'  => true,
                );         
            $this->load->library('upload', $config_arr);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
                $data['errors'] = $this->upload->display_errors(); // this isn't working
            } else {
                $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
            }

            $config=array(
                array(
                    'field'=>'firstName',
                    'label'=>'First Name',
                    'rules'=>'required|max_length[15]|min_length[3]'
                ),
                array(
                    'field'=>'city',
                    'label'=>'City',
                    'rules'=>'required'
                ),
                array(
                    'field'=>'mobile_phone',
                    'label'=>'Mobile Number',
                    'rules'=>'required'
                ),
                array(
                    'field'=>'email',
                    'label'=>'Email',
                    'rules'=>'required|is_unique[clients.email]|valid_email'
                ),
            );
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                $data['errors'] = validation_errors();
            }else{
                $data=array(
                    'img_path'=>$upload_data['file_name'],
                    'firstName'=>$_POST['firstName'],
                    'email'=>$_POST['email'],
                    'city'=>$_POST['city'],
                    'mobile_phone'=>$_POST['mobile_phone'],
                );
                $this->mdl_clients->add($data);
                $data['success'] = 1;
                $data['errors']= 0;
            }
        }
            $data['title'] = 'Add Client Database';
            $data['main_content'] = 'clients/add';
            echo Modules::run('templates/admin', $data);

    }
```

and my view file .. add.php

```
<? if($success==1) {?>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>
        Data Has been Updated ! 
    </div>
<? } ?>
<?php if($errors) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-error" >
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>
        <?=$errors?>
    </div>
<? } ?>

<?php $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal');
echo form_open_multipart('clients/add', $attributes); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <!-- Address form -->

<h2>Client Information</h2>
<hr />
All Fields Marked with <span style="color: red;">*</span> is necessary .
    <hr />

        <!-- Upload input-->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Upload<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input name="userfile" name="userfile" type="file"
                class="input-xlarge">
                <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- firstName input-->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">First Name<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name"
                class="input-xlarge" required>
                <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Email input-->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">E-Mail<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="A Valid Email Address"
                class="input-xlarge" required>
                <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- City input-->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">City<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="city" name="city" type="text" placeholder="City Name"
                class="input-xlarge" required>
                <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
        <!-- Mobile input-->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Mobile Number<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="mobile_phone" name="mobile_phone" type="text" placeholder="Current Mobile Phone Number"
                class="input-xlarge" required>
                <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <button class="btn btn-success">Add to Database</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming an input element of:

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="image">
```

Change the following line:

```
!$this->upload->do_upload()
```

to:

```
!$this->upload->do_upload('image')
```

Please let me know if you face any problem.

**UPDATE**

If you want to send it to the template then do something like this:

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {    
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg',$error['error']);
    redirect('controller_name/function_name','refresh');
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: it does't work ... like i said valid file upload is working but i think it cant pass the file validation $data['errors'] through the template ..

Comment: checked ..but not working ... i will check the whole logic again lets see if any logic goes wrong .. :(

Answer (score 0):

While doing the form validation you are not taking into consideration if there were upload errors or not. You should check if there were upload errors or not than proceed with the form validation

```
if($data['errors'] != '')
{
   //do something, probably redirect back to the view and show the errors
}
else
{
   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
      $data['errors'] = validation_errors();
   }
   else
   {
       $data=array(
           'img_path'=>$upload_data['file_name'],
           'firstName'=>$_POST['firstName'],
           'email'=>$_POST['email'],
           'city'=>$_POST['city'],
           'mobile_phone'=>$_POST['mobile_phone'],
       );
       $this->mdl_clients->add($data);
       $data['success'] = 1;
       $data['errors']= 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the ans bro .. After looking hours at my own code i have found a solution. I changed the database field from not null to null and i was sending null value to database .. that's why ...removed the } after `$upload_data = $this->upload->data();` and pasted it after `$this->mdl_clients->add($data);` . works well